# Spring Boot @Cacheable for findOne

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot

I would like to add caching to my Spring Boot 4 application.
As a key I would like to use id (type Long) of my entity, value is my entity.

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootMainApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMainApplication.class, args);
  }
}

@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("findOne");
  }
}

public interface SampleEntityService extends CrudRepository<SampleEntity, Long> {
  @Cacheable(key = "#a0", value = "findOne")
  SampleEntity findOne(Long id);
}
```

but when I call findOne method in my test I got an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleValueWrapper cannot be cast to my.springboot.model.SampleEntity
  at my.springboot.SampleEntityCacheTest.aaa(SampleEntityCacheTest.java:46)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
  at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
  at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

According to some tutorials, I tried to use many variants, but all of them fail.

```
@Cacheable(key = "#a0", value = "findOne")
@Cacheable(key = "#p0", value = "findOne")
@Cacheable(key = "a0", value = "findOne")
@Cacheable(key = "p0", value = "findOne")
@Cacheable(key = "#id", value = "findOne")
@Cacheable(key = "id", value = "findOne")
@Cacheable(key = "#root.id", value = "findOne")
@Cacheable(key = "root.id", value = "findOne")
```

What do I do wrong ?

======= answer =========

Proper solution is:

```
@Cacheable(key = "#a0", value = "findOne")
```

and inside the test I should have done something like that:

```
@Test
public void aaa() {
    SampleEntity entity = sampleEntityService.save(create("name1", uuid(1)));
    sampleEntityService.findOne(entity.getId());
    SampleEntity entityFromCache =(SampleEntity) cacheManager.getCache("findOne").get(entity.getId()).get();
    assertNotNull(entityFromCache);
}
```

Comment: You call this method inside your test (at my.springboot.SampleEntityCacheTest.aaa(SampleEntityCacheTest.java:46)) show us your test code as well please.

Comment: I added the method and I found the problem. Thanks for help !

Comment: So it was your test that was wrong not the configuration?

Comment: Yes, get on a `Cache` returns a wrapper